# Drive in readonly, after cryptsetup

Tags: linux, encryption, readonly, parted, cryptsetup

I have been having some trouble with my 16Gb USB. You see I decided to attempt to encrypt it using cryptsetup, and I have done this before without problems, but his time, when I was creating a filesystem (ntfs), my computer froze and at the end i had to perform a hard restart. 
This messed up the drive really bad! I had already installed one layer of AES 265-bit encryption, but when i open it, it seems to have a second layer of encryption. This second layer is not readable (because of the hard restart).

Basically the entire drive is locked in readonly mode.
I really hope  i can put ntfs in the drive again.

Some info (please request what you need):

BTW: The deice i would like to wipe is /dev/sdc (/dev/sdc1)

```
root@kali:~# ls -l /dev/sd*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  0 apr 15 08:32 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  1 apr 15 08:32 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  2 apr 15 08:32 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  3 apr 15 08:32 /dev/sda3
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  4 apr 15 08:32 /dev/sda4
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 apr 15 08:32 /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 17 apr 15 08:32 /dev/sdb1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 18 apr 15 08:32 /dev/sdb2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 19 apr 15 08:32 /dev/sdb3
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 32 apr 15 08:04 /dev/sdc
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 33 apr 15 08:04 /dev/sdc1
```

&

```
(parted) print devices 
/dev/sda (180GB)
/dev/sdb (124GB)
/dev/sdc (15,4GB)
/dev/mapper/luks-73c77bc9-710c-4e0a-9af7-0d1775e27acd (15,4GB)
/dev/mapper/sdb3 (121GB)
```

&

```
root@kali:~# cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sdc1
LUKS header information for /dev/sdc1

Version:        1
Cipher name:    aes
Cipher mode:    xts-plain64
Hash spec:      sha256
Payload offset: 4096
MK bits:        256
```

&

```
root@kali:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdc: 14,3 GiB, 15376000000 bytes, 30031250 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0c7b9850

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 30029823 30027776 14,3G  b W95 FAT32


Disk /dev/mapper/luks-73c77bc9-710c-4e0a-9af7-0d1775e27acd: 14,3 GiB, 15372124160 bytes, 30023680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

When i run: (notice i run as root)

```
root@kali:~# sudo umount /dev/sdc1
umount: /dev/sdc1: not mounted.
root@ralphiboi:~# sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdc1
Cluster size has been automatically set to 4096 bytes.
Initializing device with zeroes:   0%Error writing to /dev/sdc1: Operation not permitted
This should not happen.
root@kali:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc1
dd: writing to '/dev/sdc1': Operation not permitted
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0,000281734 s, 0,0 kB/s
root@kali:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc
dd: failed to open '/dev/sdc': Read-only file system
root@kali:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc1
dd: writing to '/dev/sdc1': Operation not permitted
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0,000284234 s, 0,0 kB/s
root@kali:~# sudo wipefs /dev/sdc1
offset               type
----------------------------------------------------------------
0x0                  crypto_LUKS   [crypto]
                     UUID:  73c77bc9-710c-4e0a-9af7-0d1775e27acd
```

Answer (score 1):

What I understood is you want to wipe `/dev/sdc1`.

You can do that by re-creating the file system as follows

```
sudo umount /dev/sdc1
Install ntfs-3g if already not installed
sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdc1
```

If the above method failed first fill the entire partition with zero as follows then try the above

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc1
```

**NOTE**

1. If you're more familiar with GUI you may use `Gparted` instead `mkfs`
2. Further `/dev/sdc` is not same as `/dev/sdc1`. Make sure what you want to wipe. `sdc` is the whole disk including partition table. `/dev/sdc1` is a partition on `/dev/sdc`.
3. To fill a disk with zero using `dd` is time consuming and considering disk helth it's recommend as a last resort. To wipe file system on `/dev/sdc1` you may use `wipefs` as follows.

   ```
   sudo wipefs /dev/sdc1         //this will list offset of all existing file system
   sudo wipefs -o offset /dev/sdc1 // this will wipe the actual file system
   ```
4. To remove partition table and recreate one (if necessary) you may use `fdisk` (recommend if you use `msdos` partition table) or `gdisk` (recommend if you chose GNU partition table). Alternatively `Gparted` as GUI will do the work.

Comment: It just printed exactly what i got when i was trying this before:
"Operation not permitted".

The problem isn't that i don't know how to wipe and reset a drive, but rather that i can't. It is, as i stated, created with cryptsetup. 
I need some sort of HARD OVERWRITE to bypass the cryptsetup blocking. Or instructions on how to undo the encryption (aes 256-bit). (I have the key)

Comment: @CarlJacksson With which command you're getting "Operation not permitted" Error? Is the error from `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc1`? If so try the same command appended with `sudo` i.e. `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc1`.

Comment: As i mentioned in the edited question (I run as root). sudo didn't change anything. still operation not permitted